# Is it possible to change web store url in ccavenue?

Tags: woocommerce, payment-gateway, ccavenue

I am trying to implement ccavenue payment gateway in my php site.

I need to change webstore url in ccavenue dashboard.

How can i change webstore url?

Comment: Did you get any solution for this, Please help me. I am getting same issue.

Answer (score 2):

You may change and set the Web store name as often as you like. However your website URL cannot be changed. In case you wish to change the URL kindly mark an email to compliance@ccavenue.com. This is in accordance to the documentation given on the link [here](http://mars.ccavenue.com/mer_register/support/guides/CCAVenueIndiaUserGuide.pdf)